# Making body as responsive as this?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the divs where I put the contents of my website as responsive as this: sgcafe.com

If you check and resize the browser, the contents fits on the screen perfectly, making the box larger or smaller depending on the width of the browser.

Here is what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkTe/oyf3qwvb/

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="content">box 1</div>
    <div class="content">box 2</div>
    <div class="content">box 3</div>
    <div class="content">box 4</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>

CSS:

#main {
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
.content{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #2d2d2d;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 10px;
   float: left;
```

Comment: sgcafe.com is using a Masonry. Check out: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @TheMiniJohn all right, I am checking it right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Use this library. It does exactly what your looking for. Just keep the widths and highs of the divs if you want them all the same size, and masonry will re-adjust them depending on the viewport size. Any questions let me know.

**------------------------------------------------ EDIT ---------------------------------------------**

To answer your question below, I have created a fiddle to accomplish what I think your aiming for:

http://jsfiddle.net/z4fs7nht/1/

I added:

```
transitionDuration: 1,
```

To the JavaScript which calls the Masonry to your elements (Which I found in there docs) and also added:

```
*{
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
         -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
               -o-transition:all 1s ease;
                     transition:all 1s ease;
}
```

In the CSS file. These styles give the elements there 'bounce' kind of thing they have going on when you alter the browser/viewport size.

You will notice on my fiddle example, that i've also, used media queries to change the widths of the elements when the browser changes. Changing the widths allowed me to give a more natural feel to the transition effects and also, simulate the website you we're getting your inspiration from.

/* NOTE */
I've commented out:

```
/*         background: blue; */
```

The background colour styles. I have these there, so when the window reaches that size, It will change the background colour so I can easily see the changes. You can delete them, or use the same when editing your site.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Charles, I've successfully applied masonry on my school project website, though I'm not sure if im missing something because my divs have fix size, what I want is to make the div re-adjust itself depending on the viewpoint size just like SGcafe.com, if you try to minimize the width of the site, you can see what I am trying to say. If you got any idea how its done, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late response @MarkTe Anyway, in short. You want media queries to alter the size of your divs whenever the webpage is changed. I've updated my answer to achieve what I think your trying to achieve. I've added media queries to change the width of the div when the browser changes & used transitions to give it a slight 'bounce'/transition. If you need any help or this dosn't answer it. let me know

Answer (score 0):

We now have column-width, column-gap and column-rule css properties. They are not supported by IE9 and with some tweaking of white space, you can achieve the same result as on sgcafe.com. As mini john is saying, Masonry javascript is used to make the layout. Have a try...